# Android XML Namespace not bound

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, xml-namespaces, android-productflavors

I have a strings resource file (not the main `strings.xml` file) in a specific flavor of my app that looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="stringname">String Value</string>
</resources>
```

When I run lint inspections for the project, I get a `Namespace is not bound` warning for this file, even though it looks just like the strings file in the main resource path.

I have tried adding an XML encoding declaration, as well as the various android namespaces to the opening `<resources>` tag. None of these solve the issue, and adding the namespaces generates a `URI not registered` error. Presumably this is happening because the file is not in the main resources path, but how can I resolve it?